# How are levels of a categorical variable defined in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I know that logistic regression uses 0s and 1s for the dependent variable. But how are the 0s and 1s allocated when the variable is defined as a category, "Healthy" vs. "Sick"? In other words, what is the reference level? Is "Healthy" given a 0 because H is first in the alphabet?

[Testing CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXcUt.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

```
# index_col=0 eliminates the dumb index column
baseball_train = pd.read_csv(r"baseball_train.csv",index_col=0,
                             dtype={'Opp': 'category', 'Result': 'category', 
                                    'Name': 'category'}, header=0)
baseball_test = pd.read_csv(r"baseball_test.csv",index_col=0,
                            dtype={'Opp': 'category', 'Result': 'category', 
                                   'Name': 'category'}, header=0)
```

```
# take all independent variables
X = baseball_train.iloc[:,:-1]
# drop opp and result because I don't want them
X = X.drop(['Opp','Result'],axis=1)
# dependent variable
y = baseball_train.iloc[:,-1]

# Create logistic regression
logit = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True)
```

```
model = logit.fit(X,y)
```

Here, `Name` is the dependent variable with categories: "Nolan" and "Tom" not 0s and 1s

Comment: To my knowledge, Python, the language makes no distinction for categorical data nor is categorical data defined as a data type.

Comment: How does your CSV file look like? Can you post a lines?

Comment: added the csv screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Pandas to read and encode your data, the [categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) are sorted (just like sklearn, see below).

```
import pandas as pd
import io

txt = """
HR,HBP,Name
0,0,Tommy
0,1,Nolan
0,2,Tommy
1,1,Nolan"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), dtype={'Name': 'category'})
print(df)
```

> ```
>   HR  HBP Name
> 0 0   0   Tommy
> 1 0   1   Nolan
> 2 0   2   Tommy
> 3 1   1   Nolan
> ```

If you look at the codes you can see that although Tommy was mentioned first its encoding is 1 and Nolan got 0.

```
print(df.Name.cat.codes)
```

> ```
> 0    1
> 1    0
> 2    1
> 3    0
> dtype: int8
> ```

If you want to get everything as a dictionary:

```
encoded_categories = dict(enumerate(df.Name.cat.categories))
print(encoded_categories)
```

> `{0: 'Nolan', 1: 'Tommy'}`

---

**Initial answer**

You labeled the question with `scikit-learn`, so I assume you are using `LabelEncoder` from `sklearn.preprocessing`. In that case the values are indeed sorted.

Simple example

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"])
```

`fit` calls [`_encode`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L36) which in case of a Python `list` or `tuple` (or anything except for a numpy array) sorts the it before encoding. numpy arrays are sorted as well by using `numpy.unique`.

You can check it via

```
print(le.classes_)
>> ['amsterdam' 'paris' 'tokyo']
```

So in your case

```
np.array_equal(le.fit(["healthy", "sick"]).classes_, 
               le.fit(["sick", "healthy"]).classes_)
>> True

np.array_equal(le.fit(["healthy", "sick"]).classes_, 
               le.fit(["sick", "healthy", "unknown"]).classes_)
>> False
```

Comment: @Matt: Please put the code in your question, not in the comment. Preferably with some your data from the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just know how to interpret the 1s and 0s apriori.

The following tutorial explains how to use categorical data with a very good workin example: https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-logistic-regression-in-python-step-by-step-becd4d56c9c8

Comment: Are you saying I have to manually code the variable as a 0 and 1? Because I ran a logistic regression with categories and I still got the model to fit. In R, a 2 level factor has 0 assigned to the level that is first in the alphabet. I want to know if python works the same way.

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually code the variables as 0 and 1, as I hope the tutorial demonstrates. Not being familiar with Logistic Regression in R, I can't offer a comparison insight, unfortunately.

Comment: In that dataset, the dependent variable is already coded as a 0 and 1. Someone that hasn't looked at that dataset before and has no variable descriptions would have no idea what 0 and 1 represent. So, If I have variable y with categories "Healthy" and "Sick" how do I know which category is treated as the reference level in scikit learn?

Comment: @HaydenEastwood: Where in the provided link are the variable levels defined? Can you add that section to your answer. I couldn't find it, just dummy variables.